# Disconnect bluetooth socket when application exits

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

im using this code I want to disconnect the bluetooth when the application exits but when the application exit, the socket is still connected to the bluetooth device. I think the "cancel" thread does not function in the code. What will I do to disconnect it? Thanks in Advance

```
 public class ConnectToBluetooth implements Runnable{
  private BluetoothDevice btShield;
  private BluetoothSocket mySocket = null;
  private UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

  public ConnectToBluetooth(BluetoothDevice bluetoothShield) {
  btShield = bluetoothShield;
  try{
  mySocket = btShield.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
  }catch(IOException createSocketException){
  //Problem with creating a socket
  }
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
  /* Cancel discovery on Bluetooth Adapter to prevent slow connection */
  bluetooth.cancelDiscovery();

  try{
  /*Connect to the bluetoothShield through the Socket. This will block
  until it succeeds or throws an IOException */
  mySocket.connect();
  } catch (IOException connectException){
  try{
  mySocket.close(); //try to close the socket
  }catch(IOException closeException){
  }
  return;
  }
  }

  /* Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
  public void cancel() {
  try {
  mySocket.close();
  } catch (IOException e){
  }
  }
 }
```

Comment: On Android, there's not any particularly obvious meaning of ""application exits" so first you will have to devise a meaningful criteria.

Comment: Does onbackpressed method can be used as a trigger for an event? Like closing the socket?

Comment: Is pausing (loss of foreground) of your activity the condition you want to use?

Comment: yes, somewhat like that, because when I open  the app, it will scan and connect to a specific bluetooth device. when I exit the app, I want to connect to another bluetooth device but I cannot connect because it the socket was still connected to the previous bluetooth device.